# Updated query in nested JSON with Postgres removes data

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have this JSON doc

```
    {
  "name": "Perry Street Brasserie",
  "cuisine": "French",
  "stars": 0.3,
  "address": {
    "street": "959 Iveno Square",
    "city": "Fokemlid",
    "state": "AL",
    "zipcode": "18882"
  },
  "reviews": [
    {
      "person": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "57d7a121fa937f710a7d486e"
        },
        "address": {
          "city": "Burgessborough",
          "street": "83248 Woods Extension",
          "zip": "47201"
        },
        "birthday": {
          "$date": "2011-03-17T11:21:36Z"
        },
        "email": "murillobrian@cox.net",
        "first_name": "Yvonne",
        "job": "Counselling psychologist",
        "last_name": "Pham"
      },
      "comment": "Aliquam est reiciendis alias neque ad.",
      "created_on": {
        "$date": "2018-02-01T01:56:29.627Z"
      }
    }
```

I need to change the first_name value but my queries simply remove data related to that name. So, my queries get executed successfully but end up removing data instead of updating it.

I tried the following two queries and both give me the same results

```
   UPDATE restaurants
SET info = jsonb_set('{"reviews":["person"]}', '{"first_name"}', '"Vedat"', true)
WHERE info ->'reviews'-> 0 -> 'person' ->> 'first_name' = 'John'


UPDATE restaurants
SET info = info::jsonb - 'first_name' || '{"reviews":[{"person": {"first_name":"Vedat"}}]}'
WHERE info::json->'reviews'-> 0 -> 'person' ->> 'first_name' = 'Jenna'
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing in the whole column as the first value, and you need to provide a path to the value you want to change in the form of an array:

For example:

```
UPDATE restaurants
SET info = jsonb_set(info, '{reviews,0,person,first_name}', '"Vedat"', true)
WHERE info->'reviews'->0->'person'->>'first_name' = 'John';
```

So you effectively have to pass the whole JSON document to jsonb_set, and it will return the modified document.

Regards

Thom

Comment: Oh what a shallow mistake on my end, thanks a lot that would've saved me hours

Comment: I would gladly do that but I don't have the reputation for that yet

Comment: Ah, I obviously don't know how that part of the site works.  Understood.

Comment: Do you have any clue how I would select every element in an array apart from the first one : 0 ?